# Is there a word for a person or action where they no longer believe in something?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am not looking for "apostate". Rather, I am looking for the word (verb/noun) which means that someone no longer thinks along those lines as they did before. In short, they gave up their old ideas.

Comment: Should it be negative (like "turncoat") or positive (like "open minded")?

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/apostate

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/skeptic

Comment: They have *changed their mind* or they had a *change of heart*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘To recant (on ones position)’ might fit what you’re looking for.

If it’s more religious in context then ‘to lose (ones) faith/belief’ is a good fit.